# sources folder do not have error marks on files or packages in project explorer eclipse 2022-03

Tags: java, eclipse, project-explorer

There exist some errors in the project I work on..
But the red-cross mark representing error is not marked on the package containing the erroneous file or the on the file itself. It is shown only in the file structure view below

[image]

refer above image

It ideally should be marked at 1 as well!

This leaves me with no choice but keep expanding each folder in the simple file structure view which is not very convenient or time-efficient!

Moreover, sometimes it also stops showing errors in problems/markers view which makes it impossible again to track and remove errors - (not very persistent problem)

I tried cleaning projects, cleaning tomcat directory, restarting eclipse and even the machine itself but
Even online searches did not help, the same scenario seems a bit rare on internet

FYI,

I do not remember doing any kind of change that may have resulted in such problem

One thing I doubt is that the files are being changed externally(VS Code) too, but still if the error is found in the lower simple file structure view then it also should be shown in the upper source-folder view

Please help in bringing back eclipse in it's ideal working state!

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like bug 579170.  https://bugs.eclipse.org/579170

Comment: Same problem here, right after updating to 2022-03. Seems to only happen with projects that are WAR package (<packaging>war</packaging> in maven). Is it the same for you?

Comment: @lucasdclopes yes, mine is a spring mvc project which is packaged into WAR for deployment on tomcat. But I don't think the bug has anything to do with war packaging. Then again, I am not much experienced in how the IDE work in the background.